# Facebook post 360 image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, panoramas, 360-degrees

I am having trouble posting a 360 image on Facebook via the Graph API. I can post an image just fine though. The issue is that the meta data I used for the image seems to be not working for some reasons. When I manually upload the image it is detected as a 360 image but not programatically. Is there something I am missing? A parameter missing in my spherical_metadata or a wrong parameter?

Here is the code I use to post a photo on facebook:

```
function Facebook_Share(textToPost)
{
    var imgURL="http://panorama.2020.net/view/ybcjxd4hugnmeyvaorug/panorama.jpg";
    FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
        message: textToPost,
        spherical_metadata : { "ProjectionType" : "equirectangular", "CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels" : "1696", "CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels" : "848", "FullPanoWidthPixels" : "4000",
            "FullPanoHeightPixels" : "2000", "CroppedAreaLeftPixels" : "566", "CroppedAreaTopPixels" : "283" },
        url:imgURL        
    },  function(response){

        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "";
        }
    });
}
```

PS: The site url isn't the one i'm using right now to test my facebook image. I only use it to retrieve the image until my feature is working properly.

Comment: Never mind I managed to make it 360 on facebook. The parameter ""allow_spherical_photo": true" was missing in my FB.API call...

Comment: I added your comment as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

To make it 360 on facebook, add the parameter `"allow_spherical_photo": true` in the FB.API call.